# Ember.js with Ember-data. Model object _attributes not persisting to _data on save

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to understand how the ember-data model moves data from the `_internalModel._attributes` object to the `_internalModel._data` object.

In my case I am calling `item.set('val', foo)`, where `'val'` is a attribute on my `item` model definition, but when I call `item.save()` the `'val'` attribute is unchanged from the value it had before I called `item.set()`...

Typically calling `.set()` then `.save()` works without fail, even if I'm creating synthetic attributes on the fly. Can anyone explain why it would not persist the value to the _data object to be saved?

### Source

*controller.js*

```
...
actions: {
  saveItem(clickedItem) {
    const flashMessages = Ember.get(this, 'flashMessages');
    this.store.find('fid', this.get('device.selectedFid.fid_id')).then(response => {
      clickedItem.setProperties({
        foo: this.get('selectedAccount').get('group_id'),
        bar: response,
        baz: this.get('device.selectedFid.iccid'),
        fooBaz: this.get('selectedProduct.product_type_id'),
        val: (new Moment(clickedItem.get('newVal'))).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
      });

      clickedItem.save().then((result) => {
          flashMessages.success(result.get('item_name') + ' Successfully Saved!');
          this.incrementProperty('refreshCounter');
        }, (error) => {
          flashMessages.danger('ERROR: Saving Item: ' + error);
          this.incrementProperty('refreshCounter');
        }
      );

      this.set('editingItem', false);
    });
  }
}
```

*model.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';
const computed = Ember.computed;
const attr = DS.attr;
const Model = DS.Model;

export default Model.extend({
  foo: attr('number'),
  bar: attr('string'),
  baz: attr('number'),
  val: attr('date')
});
```

*template.hbs*

```
<tbody>
    {{#each this as |item|}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.foo}}</td>
            <td>{{item.bar}}</td>
            <td>{{item.baz}}</td>
            <td>
                <button {{action 'edititem' item}}>Edit</button>
                <button {{action 'deleteitem' item}}>Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you share the code how you test it that you see `val` is unchanged?

Comment: I am using the Chrome Inspector with a breakpoint on the line where I call .save(). Once it breaks I'm watching `item` which evaluates out to a Class. If I expand `item._internalModel._attributes` and `item._internalModel._data` that is where I'm finding that `val` is unchanged after the `.set()` is called.

This could be accomplished by adding:
`console.log(item._internalModel._data);
console.log(item._internalModel._attributes);`
after the `.set()` is called.

Comment: You sure you check after you call `.save()` when the promise is resolved? Like in `.save().then(... check here ...)`. Because it might not be ready yet coz it's async.

Comment: If I check the network tab it shows that the Request Payload is being sent out with the old value of `val`. It also shows up on my API backend as the old value.

Comment: Okey, can you share your model definition code and real fragment of code where you call set and save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was with the ember-data `DS.attr('date')` transformer. I'm not sure why it was failing and no errors were being thrown. But when I used a custom transformer `item.val` was correctly pushed through to my API backend.

Here is the code for the custom transformer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Moment from 'moment';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return new Moment.utc(value);
  },

  serialize: function(value) {
    return value && new Moment(value).isValid() ? value.toJSON() : null;
  }
});
```